# Treat functions as sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Would it be plausible within writing proofs in set theory for a function $f(x)$ to be treated as a set for the sake of using operators (specifically unions and interjections) in set theory? In my case the example is $f(x)_1 \cup f(x)_2$.

Comment: Retagged the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (one approach to) functions are just special cases of [relations in set-theoretic terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation)

A (binary) relation $R$ on set $A$ is a subset of the cartesian product $A \times A$, i.e

$$R \subseteq A \times A$$

A (single-valued) function $f$ from a set $A$ to a set $B$, i.e $f: A \to B$ is then equivalent to:

$$R_f \subseteq A \times B = \{(a, b) | a \in A, b \in B\}$$

where $R_f$ represents the binary relation associated with the function $f$ (also called the [graph of the function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function)) and $b=f(a)$.

It is clear that for any two functions $f_1$, $f_2$ which have the same domain and co-domain (image), i.e same sets $A$ and $B$ and the same relations $R_{f_1} = R_{f_2}$ then they represent the exact same functions ($f_1 \sim f_2$) and vice-versa.

In this sense the intersection and/or union of functions can be performed, set-theoreticaly, on their associated *relations*

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what you are trying to do. The best way (that I know of) is to identify a function $f:A\to B$ with its graph, i.e. the set $\{(x,f(x))|x\in A\}\subset A\times B$.